# How to create per workspace snippets in VSCode?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I would like to add some project specific snippets.

How can I add snippets in the `.vscode` folder?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Project Level Snippets** were added in the [September 2018 Release of VSCode (version 1.28)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_project-level-snippets):

> Snippets can now be scoped to a project and shared with your team. Use the **Preferences: Configure User Snippets** command or create `*.code-snippets` file in the `.vscode` folder.
>
> Project snippets work just like other snippets, they show up in IntelliSense and in the **Insert Snippet** action where they now have their own category.
>
> [image: Project Level Snippet]
>
> Snippets also now support multiple prefixes. If you cannot decide if your copyright header snippet should be prefixed as `header`, `stub`, or `copyright`, you can have them all. Use a string array as the `prefix` property.
>
> ```
> {
>   "prefix": ["header", "stub", "copyright"],
>   "body": "Copyright. Foo Corp 2028",
>   "description": "Adds copyright...",
>   "scope": "javascript,typescript"
> }
> ```

Comment: Sadly, unless I didn't understand something, this is a per **project** solution, not a per **workspace** :/

Comment: @Regnareb, project snippets will be available for all projects in any workspace having this project

Answer (score 21):

Per [this solution on vscode issues in github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/8102#issuecomment-423476360), you just need to:

1. Create a file with `.code-snippets` extension (e.g. `typescript.code-snippets`), and
2. Add the content you have in mind to that file. e.g. a simple `fog` snippet for `console.log`:

```js
{
    "Print to console": {
        "prefix": "fog",
        "body": [
            "console.log('$1');",
            "$2"
        ],
        "description": "Log output to console"
    }
}
```

3. Put that file in the `.vscode` folder of the workspace (but not inside subfolders of that).

It works like a charm on VS Code 1.36.1.

Answer (score 8):

Go to `File -> Prefrences -> User snippets`. 
Choose `New Snippets for ${project name}`. 
Give the snippet file a name of your choice. 
Read the comment in the file just created, and copy the example to create the first snippet.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is simply not possible directly in VS Code. After having read the VS Code documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets <-- I find no mention of this being possible.

Have a nice day.

Comment: true hopefully they will support this

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi actually I just had one more look. It seems that there is a snippet that might be able to do this. See: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.project-snippets <-- I testing it now....wanted to share it with you.