# Snippets accept with tab but autocomplete disabled unless press ctrl+space

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, vscode-snippets

I would like to have autocomplete disabled (unless I press ctrl+space), but also I want to be able to create snippets that populate with tab. How can I have both of these at once?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if I understood you correctly. Here are my opinion， in my understanding.

As for creat snippets, the vscode docs have gien the solution: [enter link description here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets). To simplify, **Code -> Prefrences -> User snippets** and then **New Global Snippets file**. Or you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312494/how-to-create-per-workspace-snippets-in-vscode).

Besides, to disable autocomplete, there are several options:

```
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

...

each has different functions, you can also see the official docs, or I also found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911977/prevent-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code) which may be helpful.
Hope useful.